# Why is different a variable or a copy of the variable?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a simple program in Scala using Akka and I have the following scenario: I have two different kinds of simple actors (`FooActor` and `BarActor`). The `FooActor` receives an `ActorRef` through the constructor, who represents some actor to whom the `FooActor` should deliver his answer (the original sender). This original sender is given by the `BarActor`. My question is: why is different to pass in the constructor the local `sender` and passing a local variable which was previously assigned with the `sender` value? Are they references or they hold the reference inside the obect? What is happening under the hood? Thanks. Here is the code:

```
import akka.actor._

case class foo(x: Int) // some dummy message to test

class FooActor(originalSender: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  println("[" + self.path + "] originalSender = " + originalSender) // print the sender

  override def receive = {
    // (...)
    case _ =>
  }
}

class BarActor extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case foo(x) =>

      // variant 1: this prints deadLetters as the sender in the FooActor
      context.actorOf(Props(new FooActor(sender)), "foo" + x)

      // variant 2: this prints the original sender correctly 
      // val originalSender = sender 
      // context.actorOf(Props(new FooActor(originalSender)), "foo" + x)

    case _ =>
  }
}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("my-system")

    val sender = system.actorOf(Props[BarActor], "sender") // this would be the original sender
    val bar = system.actorOf(Props[BarActor], "bar") // this is the intermediate actor, who passes the sender

    bar.tell(foo(1), sender)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer lies in the signature of [`Props.apply`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/c0235ceee6636643ef05d7c4ea7286261dc5563a/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Props.scala#L84) method.

```
def apply[T <: Actor: ClassTag](creator: ⇒ T): Props = ...
```

It takes parameter by name. This combined with the fact that `sender()` inside an actor is a method and not a val, brings you to situation where `sender()` is called sometime later (when `creator` is evaluated) when actor is no more processing the original message, thus returning a ref to `DeadLetters`.

Comment: Nice))) Thanks. I see it now. Very interesting, but can cause tricky pitfalls also.